# CCombobox - How to show full dropdownlist?

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, ownerdrawn

I am setting Owner Draw property combined with `HasStrings` for `CComboBox`,

However when there is more than one item, the dropdown does not show Full.

Can I change this mechanism?

[image]

Comment: You probably need [`CComboBox::SetMinVisibleItems()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=msvc-160#setminvisibleitems).

Comment: Hi @Ruks, I tried using this  function, it's weird that the function returns TRUE but the dropdown still shows as my image .

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Why does the size of a combo box include the size of the drop-down?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060310-17/?p=31973)

Comment: Do you have `MeasureString` method updating its parameter with correct values?

Comment: Do your menu items have varying heights per item or one height that is the same for all?

Comment: Hi everyone, Thanks all! I haven't been able to verify the answers yet because the project was quite urgent at that time. i solved using `CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style combine HasString` instead and it works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

At design time, select your combobox:
[image]

The click again on combobox:

[image]

As you see, you have a handle from where you can increase your vertical size of your combobox as you wish:

[image]

At runtime you'll see the drop down list as you designed.

Comment: That's how I do it, but maybe OP wants to be able to tweak it at runtime?  That defined height at Design time is the MAXIMUM (the list box height adjusts to its content at runtime), HOWEVER, I am not sure how OwnerDraw affects this behavior (vs. fixed size item height).